# Android: css doesnt respect the bold font

Tags: android, css

I am getting a html from a server. I want it to have the Helvetica font. I wrote a css to do this.

```
_body = "<html><head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeue_Thin';src: url('file:///android_asset/HelveticaNeue_Thin.ttf');}body {font-family: 'HelveticaNeue_Thin';color:black;text-align:left;font-size:17px;}</style></head><body>" +HTML+ "</body></html>";
```

It is working, but the bold font in the html is not respected anymore in my css. why?

Comment: hey man the font which you is a thin font means it can only be of max weight equal to 400 or 500 not bold which is 700 or 800.

Comment: even if I use any other helvetica font, the font of words having a bold one are not respected!

Comment: give me the link of the font that you have downloaded!

Comment: http://www.fontsner.com/download/12539

Comment: what is font-size? 32px or 48px or 24px or 16px or 14px?

Comment: http://ttfonts.net/font/20176_HelveticaNeue.htm

Comment: Thank you Aspiring Aqib, but it is nit what i want. The font you gave to me is entirely bold. What i want is helvetica font that keeps the bold for some words.

Comment: hey man use both in css! for normal use your one and for bold text use my one ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use bolding, you need a bold typeface of the font being used. I don’t think you can legally use a bold typeface, or any typeface for that matter, of a real Helvetica as a downloadable font (web font), so consider trying to find a suitable free font that exists in font weights that you need.

Comment: mmmm u mean if i want to use helvetica, it will be impossible to respect the bold fonts if any :S

Comment: No, I mean you cannot legally use Helvetica at all as a web font.